# Conjugate vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

What are conjugate vectors?
Can I have an example of it?

[ This question is in respect to finding the roots of equations with conjugate direction methods]

Comment: Perhaps you can give a little more context: are you talking of complex vectors, do you some inner product...?

Answer (score 11):

> What are conjugate vectors?

I was confused by this too. The word conjugate is quite an [overloaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugation) one in Math. The [plain English definition](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/conjugate) of the word is hard enough to follow and seems to bear little intuitive relationship to the various Mathematical concepts. Anyway:

The concept of conjugate vectors is closely related to orthogonal vectors and linearly independence of vectors. However a conjugates are *always* defined w.r.t. some positive definite square Matrix:

Let $u,v$ be vectors in $R^n$ and let $A$ be a positive definite $n\times n$ matrix. $u$ and $v$ are said to be mutually $A$-conjugate if and only if $u^TAv = 0$ <sup>[1](https://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~lovetrij/cECE7670/2005/Slides/slides4.pdf)</sup>.

If $u,v$ are conjugate vectors any two vectors parallel to $u$ and $v$ respectively are also conjugate. So you'll often hear speak of conjugate *directions* rather than *vectors* as the scale doesn't matter. Also, any set of mutually $X$-conjugate vectors for some positive definite $n\times n$ matrix $X$ is also *linearly independent*. So in the rough, you can think if conjugate vectors as a stricter form of linearly independent vectors.

> Can I have an example of it?

$u = (1,1), v = (1,-1) \text{ w.r.t the identity matrix } I_2$

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you *only* are interested in roots of polynomials (but then I can't understand why the "vectors" thing...), then all the roots of some given, fixed irreducible polynomial over some given field are called conjugate (elements, roots, etc.)